# Getting TTM income statement yahoo finance using yahoo_fin

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I try to get ttm values of the income statement for ticker symbol AAPL by using

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

income_statement = si.get_income_statement("aapl")
income_statement
```

but the result doesn't show the ttm values, only the yearly values are shown
[image]

On yahoo finance, we can also see the ttm values:

[image]

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't get the exact same table you see on the website is because of the way yahoo_fin gets data from Yahoo. Rather than getting them from the table you see, they get them from json data that Yahoo provides. In this data, there are both quarterly and yearly income statements. When Yahoo renders the table on their website, they most likely use the yearly data for the yearly columns and then sum the last 4 quarterly results to get the TTM column (as TTM results are nothing else than the sum of the last 4 quarterly results).

If you want to get the TTM data, the best approach would be to do it the same way I assume Yahoo does. Get the quarterly data using `yahoo_fin` and then sum the quarters to calculate the TTM results. You can do this by setting the optional `yearly` parameter to `False`:

```
quarterly_income_statement = si.get_income_statement("aapl", yearly=False)
```

You can check out their method [`_parse_json`](https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin/blob/master/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py#L370) to better understand how they get and parse data from Yahoo. (Assuming you have some knowledge of requests and json.)

##### Summing the data

To get the sum of the quarters you can for example do this:

```
quarterly_income_statement = si.get_income_statement("aapl", yearly=False)
ttm = quarterly_income_statement.sum(axis=1)
```

This will give you a new `Dataframe` `ttm` with the same data fields with values being TTM (You can test it and see if it matches the numbers on the website).

Comment: Thank you so much FIlip Müller. May be u can help me out. How can I sum the 4 quarters, I am not a real programmer and have some hard time, solving the issue. TY!

Comment: I added a way to sum the data into a new Dataframe to the answer. If you want to modify the data to not be floats but integers or connect the TTM column to the yearly dataframe, you will find a lot of information about that online.